# I want to create a file but it does not work

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to create a file and write into that file, but I haven't managed to get the create file to work. No errors or anything appear but the text file doesn't appear. I read some ebooks about them and checked out posts but it didnt work with me. Here is my code:

```
.model small          
.stack 100
.data 


filePath db "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\io\name.txt",0  
handler dw ?


.code
START:          
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

;create file
  mov  ah, 3ch
  mov  cx, 0
  mov  dx, offset filePath
  int  21h

  mov handler, ax  



    end start
```

Comment: And what is the value of `ax` and the status of the Carry flag after the interrupt?

Comment: @fuz : while it doesn't support every call, it does support file creation with int 3ch. My guess is the CF flag was set and the value of 3 is in AL as an error code which would be path not found. The problem is that when running emulated in emu8086 the path `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\io\name.txt` is actually `c:\emu8086\vdrive\c\Users\myUser\Desktop\io\name.txt` and I will guess that path doesn't exist. If no drive is specified it is relative to `c:\emu8086\MyBuild` instead of *c:\emu8086\vdrive\<driveletter>\*

Comment: @MIchael has asked the right question. What is the value in AX and if you click the `flags` button on the window that displays registers while debugging .. what does the Carry Flag (CF) have in it right after int 21h.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Interesting.  I did a quick look to see if making files is supported and found that it is not.  It seems this was added in some recent version.

Comment: @fuz : I'm using 4.08 here. It is possible an earlier version didn't support it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't have a copy and I was unable to find a manual anywhere.

Comment: @fuz : The docs I use are here: http://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_and_DOS_interrupts.pdf

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch , I changed my path to c:\emu8086\MyBuild and it worked! I think you're supposed to post it as an answer now so that I can make a thumbs up ^^

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question!